# Could any symplectic matrix be reduced to the standard symplectic one?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, linear-transformations, symplectic-geometry

Maybe it's an elementary fact, but I couldn't find a point where it's explicitly stated.

Consider the $2n$-dimensional standard symplectic matrix, i.e.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & I_n \\
    -I_n & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$

Where $I_n$ is the $n$-dimensional identity matrix.

- Could (in principle) *any* symplectic (real) matrix be brought in such form
  (by means of a linear trasformation represented by another real symplectic
  matrix)?
- Is this a conclusion derived from the [Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem)?

Comment: No, the Darboux Theorem is far deeper because it involves differential equations on an open coordinate neighborhood. It's just a normal form for a skew-symmetric matrix of maximal rank. One way to convince yourself is to complexify and use the spectral theorem. You can also probably do an induction argument, if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you @TedShifrin. I know Darboux theorem is far deeper than the question I've posed. Indeed I specifically don't want to pass through complexification...could you (if possibile) just sketch or suggest the induction argument as you mean it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: As I said earlier, you have to assume the matrix $A$ is $2n\times 2n$ with maximal rank, so the bilinear form $\langle x,y\rangle = x^\top Ay$ is nondegenerate.  Then you will show that you can decompose $V=\Bbb R^{2n}$ as a sum of $n$ invariant $2$-dimensional subspaces, on each of which the bilinear form has the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Choose $v_1,v_2\in V$ so that $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle\ne 0$. (It follows from nondegeneracy that you can do this.) By scaling $v_2$, we can assume $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle = 1$. Note that $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent (why?). Then $v_1,v_2$ span the first subspace. Now write $V = \text{Span}(v_1,v_2) \oplus \left(\text{Span}(v_1,v_2)\right)^\perp$ and proceed by induction.

At the very end, you can reorder your basis vectors to get the matrix form you desire.